# Title of the page in google result for a pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, http-headers

It's a classic problem I think but I have not found any solution to this problem yet.
Here is the problem.

Google displays pdf with titles that are not present in the PDF meta or in the meta in the HTTP page.

my controller :

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', '');
$response->headers->set('Last-Modified', gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s'));
$contentDisposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $nameFileDownload, $nameFileback);
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $contentDisposition);

return $response;
```

Someone to an idea to work around this problem?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, a quick check showed that Google seems to show appropriate titles for the PDFs we have indexed in a customer project - and those are just PDFs served normally & directly by the web server.

Comment: Do you have an example url?